# Running SPARQL Queries on turtle file

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, turtle-rdf

I'm trying to run SPARQL queries on turtle files using python, but my sparql returns all the entries, how can I return the entry with name="Idham Al-Taif Mahmoud"?

turtle file:

```
<http://example.org/person/a6376-dh3642> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasName> "Idham Al-Taif Mahmoud".
<http://example.org/person/a6376-dh3642> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/diedOn> "28 Feb 2017".
<http://example.org/person/a6376-dh3642> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasAge> "adult".
<http://example.org/person/a6376-dh3642> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasSex> "male".
<http://example.org/person/a6376-dh3642> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/diedIn> "Samarra, south of Salah Al-Din".
<http://example.org/person/a6363-fn3690> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasName> "Shukran Ghanim Hussein".
<http://example.org/person/a6363-fn3690> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/diedOn> "26 Feb 2017".
<http://example.org/person/a6363-fn3690> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasAge> "child".
<http://example.org/person/a6363-fn3690> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasSex> "male".
<http://example.org/person/a6363-fn3690> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/diedIn> "Hay Koor, west Mosul".
<http://example.org/person/a6348-sz3469> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasName> "Munther Al-Ajaj ".
<http://example.org/person/a6348-sz3469> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasMaritalStatus> "married".
<http://example.org/person/a6348-sz3469> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasParentalStatus> "parent".
<http://example.org/person/a6348-sz3469> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/diedOn> "25 Feb 2017".
<http://example.org/person/a6348-sz3469> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasAge> "adult".
<http://example.org/person/a6348-sz3469> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasSex> "male".
<http://example.org/person/a6348-sz3469> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/diedIn> "Al-Mazra'a village, Baiji, north of Salah Al-Din".
<http://example.org/person/a6381-xz3480> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasName> "Shifa Gerdi/Born Shifa Zikri Ibrahim Gerdi".
<http://example.org/person/a6381-xz3480> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/diedOn> "25 Feb 2017".
<http://example.org/person/a6381-xz3480> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasAge> "young adult".
<http://example.org/person/a6381-xz3480> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasSex> "female".
<http://example.org/person/a6381-xz3480> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/diedIn> "west Mosul".
```

python code:

```
import rdflib

filename = "turtle.ttl"


g = rdflib.Graph()

result = g.parse(filename, format='ttl')
print(result)

query = """

SELECT ?person
WHERE {
    ?person <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasName> "Idham Al-Taif Mahmoud"
}

"""

g.query(query)
for stmt in g:
    print(stmt)
```

Comment: You seem to be printing the graph. `for stmt in g:` not the query results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your issue is with the methods. [Here](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html) is a link with a nice example of what you want to do.

The following script works for me:

```
import rdflib
  
filename = "turtle.ttl"


g = rdflib.Graph()

g.parse(filename, format='ttl')

query = """

SELECT ?person
WHERE {
    ?person <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hasName> "Idham Al-Taif Mahmoud"
}

"""

qres = g.query(query)

for row in qres :
        print("%s" % row)
```

Notice that I assign the results of the query to a new variable `qres`, and also that the `parse` method is void, i.e. it does not return a value like you had.

The `%` signs in the end are just to print a human readable result, but you can totally get rid of them.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. Do you know what SPARQL query I need to write to get only the name of the person returned rather than "http://example.org/person/a6376-dh3642"?

Comment: You mean that you want to see `"Idham Al-Taif Mahmoud"`?

Comment: Yeah, precisely. How can I get data about the person rather than the URI returned?

Comment: then you have to add another triple pattern that gets the additional data or their name (which clearly doesn't make sense here as you query by name, thus, you have the name) .